# Best practices in working with Intellij IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

I would like to ask your advise on how to do auto build gradle project with IDEA? On eclipse I could not worry, when I add some dependency, because eclipse did everything for me, but on IDEA I need to push synchronize button.

I found this article on IDEA official site, https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/synchronizing-changes-in-gradle-project-and-intellij-idea-project.html

What I'm asking is how to do auto build?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do is if you are using Intellij Idea 14 or later then while importing Gradle project enable auto import by enabling 'use auto-import' check box.

[image: Auto Import]

Answer (score -1):

Try this plugin

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/?id=3822

It enables auto-make project on every save.